# Why is 'break' in JS forEach function not allowed?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I've done quite a bit of reading and seen many different questions regarding this topic, but I was wondering if I could get help on WHY breaking out of a For Each loop doesn't work. Also, I am pretty new, so I apologize in advance if this question was answered in a different way that I wasn't able to understand.

So far, I have written a forEach function to emulate a native .forEach method:

```
function forEach(collection, callback){
  if(collection.isArray){
    for(var i =0;i<collection.length&&callback(collection[i])!==false;i++){
      callback(collection[i]);
    }
  }else{
    for(var key in collection){
      callback(collection[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to utilize this to write another function 'find' that searches for the first instance of the array that matches a criteria, using 'return' or 'break' doesn't seem to work. find([1,2,3,4,5].function(x){return x>3;}); returns 5 instead of 4.

```
function find (collection, criteria){
  var result;
  forEach(collection, function(x){
    if(criteria(x)){
      result =x;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

I have been able to recreate the effect that I want using other functions, but would like to understand why this doesn't work, as I am learning how to implement the use of functions within other functions.

Thank you.

Comment: You return from the function - why would you expect THAT to have any effect on the for loop? Your function does an implicit `return` anyway even if you leave out that word, by the way.

Comment: Break is defined only for loops, switches or labels in the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the behavior of `bar` in this code snippet:

```
function foo(x) {
    return x;
}

function bar() {
    foo(1);
    foo(2);
    return 3;
}

console.log(bar());
```

It calls `foo`, which returns, but it is returning control back to `bar` itself, not to the caller of `bar`, so this logs 3.

The situation does not change if we put the definition of `foo` inside `bar`:

```
function bar() {
    function foo(x) {
        return x;
    }

    foo(1);
    foo(2);
    return 3;
}

console.log(bar());
```

Nor does it change if we accept it as a parameter:

```
function foo(x) {
    return x;
}

function bar(baz) {
    baz(1);
    baz(2);
    return 3;
}

console.log(bar(foo));
```

The behavior does not change when we use a function expression, either:

```
function bar(baz) {
    baz(1);
    baz(2);
    return 3;
}

console.log(bar(function(x) {
    return x;
}));
```

So the reason `return` does not work the way you are expecting from a function passed to `forEach` is that `return` retains its usual meaning of returning from the function it is in—not the function that lexically encloses that function. Similarly, `break` is illegal because it is not in a loop; it is in a function (that only happens to be called in a loop later on).

Comment: Really appreciate this answer - very concisely and clearly written with good examples.

Answer (score 0):

For an array, `collection.isArray` is `undefined`. You should replace this with `Array.isArray(collection)`.

For non-array types, you're not checking the return value of `callback(collection[key])`.